# Manipulate gltf model children

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

I'VE loaded a GLTF file with 2 mesh object in it (cube1, cube2) and rendered it, looks OK.

The problem is this :

I'm trying to manipulate the opacity / scale of those objects separately.

Tried to address them with:

```
Var cube1 = gltf.Scene.GetObjectByName('Cube1');
```

But when I try to define `cube1.opacity`, I get an "undefined" error.

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked inside the scene to see the actual names? [This article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-gltf.html) uses some code to print out the scene graph. You can also inspect the graph [in the debugger](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-debugging-javascript.html) In other words are you sure it's name "Cube1" not "cube1" or "Cube_1" or "cube-1" etc.? Otherwise, once you find the mesh it would probably be `mesh.material.opacity` not `mesh.opacity`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't enable transparency of the material I was trying to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... even tho' the question is simple, the answer not so much.

First you are using a loader, usually this implies that your cube model will be a bit more complicated. You will go something like this:

3D Object > Children > Mesh [x] > material > Opacity

I have a live example here:
https://boxelizer.com/renderer.php?mid=7740369e824e4eadbd83e6f01fa96caa

In which you can go into the console and change that property like this:

```
model.children[1].material.transparent = true;
model.children[1].material.opacity = .5;
model.children[1].material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Your model may be a bit different but I hope this example helps you figure out yours.

Comment: yes, thanks , this one has to be true as well i think.:    material.premultipliedalpha = true